# Clone private git repository from Dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, ssh, ssh-keys

My goal is to clone a private repository from a Dockerfile. I copy my private SSH key then add bitbucket.org domain to the `known_hosts` file, but when I try to clone the repository I get "Permission denied" error for some reason. I can clone this repository from my host though. What do I miss?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git ssh

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN git clone git@bitbucket.org:foo/bar.git
```

Command:

```
docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" .
```

Output:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '18.205.93.2' to the list of known hosts.
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

RUN ssh -v git@bitbucket.org output:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [18.205.93.0] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_b9a79bcd5e-dirty conker-3002
debug1: no match: conker_b9a79bdd5e-dirty conker-3002
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuEwbHaxvSc0ojez6sdf6s9YXaGp1A
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '18.205.93.0' to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Make sure you set your SSH_PRIVATE_KEY correctly when building. Probably your build command should be `docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa) .`

Comment: I updated the command but still receive the same error.

Comment: try again with double quotes, I got it working that way.

Comment: You should use and ssh-key without passphrase. Otherwise this will get very complicated

Comment: Two things to remember with this setup: it's really easy to get the private key back out if you have the image, and Docker layer caching means it generally won't repeat a `git clone` step.  I'd highly recommend running `git` outside of Docker and avoiding this sequence entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that id_rsa is filled correctly:

```
docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" .
```

**EDIT**
this works only for a key without passphrase, otherwise things will get complicated.

Comment: I regenerated keys without a passphrase and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[*note* : not a direct answer, more of a formatted comment]

You need to debug further your setup :

- check the content of `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` in your image :

  ```
  RUN cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa
  ```
- check what `ssh -v` says when you try to contact bitbucket (does it use the key `id_rsa` ?) :

  ```
  RUN ssh -v git@bitbucket.org
  ```

Comment: `RUN cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa` shows me key from the host machine. I guess that part works.

Comment: Added output of `RUN ssh -v git@bitbucket.org` to the question.